# Pushover API error sending message in PHP

Tags: php, api

So I'm following the Pushover FAQ example for PHP:

```
<?php
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
  "token" => "APP_TOKEN",
  "user" => "USER_KEY",
  "message" => "hello world",
)));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

That example works great, but if I try to send the message as a variable like:

```
"message" => $variable,
```

It gives me an error saying that I can't send a blank message.
I guess it's a language related problem. How can I assign a variable to the array "message"?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you verified that `$variable` actually contains a value?

Comment: Yes, I always print the variable before sending it. I just tried to first put: `$variable='test';` and it works. So I guess it's a problem of the variable itself. I'm trying to send a tweet like: `$variable=$tweet.' '.$url`. That shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Still don't know what the problem was but I solved it puting a blank space at the begining of the variable: `$variable=" ".$variable;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a problem with Curl, you can use this function to post array data into api.pushover.

```
function sendApiPushover(){
$url  = 'https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json';
$data = array(
            "token" => "APP_TOKEN",
            "user" => "USER_KEY",
            "title" => "John",
            "message" => "hello world"
        );

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result  = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your variable $message is empty. Better to check before running this script by:

```
<?php
if(!empty($message)){
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
  "token" => "APP_TOKEN",
  "user" => "USER_KEY",
  "message" => $message,
)));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I always print the message first and this isn't the problem.

Comment: just read your comment, on you post. I have had this before. Most likely the $variable is an object with a magic method _toString(). This means when you echo or print it basically calls this _toString method inside the object. But if you copy the object as in $variable = $object; then the variable does not become a string but a copy of the object.